# auto arima with R and Python

Tags: python, r, forecast

I am comparing results of auto ARIMA with R (forecast package) and Python (pmdarima package). One of the issues I am getting is the length of the residuals in R and Python are different when d is not zero. For example, in the code shown below, in R, the length of the residuals is the same as the time series data but in python it is the length of the time series data  minus d. Further, I also see significant changes in the order I get from R vs Python. What are the causes of the differences?

**R**

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(250)
ts1 = arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)
set.seed(270)
ts2 = arima.sim(list(order = c(1,2,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)
my_fit1 <- auto.arima(ts1, stepwise = FALSE)
resid1 = as.numeric(residuals(my_fit1))
my_fit2 <- auto.arima(ts2, stepwise = FALSE)
resid2 = as.numeric(residuals(my_fit2))
#to use with Python
 ts1 = data.frame(ts1 = ts1)
 write.csv(ts1, 'ts1.csv', row.names = F)
 ts2 = data.frame(ts2 = ts2)
 write.csv(ts2, 'ts2.csv', row.names = F)
```

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
ts1 = pd.read_csv('ts1.csv')
ts2 = pd.read_csv('ts2.csv')
my_fit1 = auto_arima(y = ts1.ts1, 
                  start_p=1, 
                  start_q=1,
                  max_p=3, 
                  max_q=3,
                  seasonal=False,
                  d = None,  
                  error_action='ignore',  
                  suppress_warnings=True, 
                  stepwise=False)

 my_fit2 = auto_arima(y = ts2.ts2, 
                  start_p=1, 
                  start_q=1,
                  max_p=3, 
                  max_q=3,
                  seasonal=False,
                  d = None,  
                  error_action='ignore',  
                  suppress_warnings=True, 
                  stepwise=False)
```